# Resetting image view

Tags: java, android, xml

In an app, I am setting the image view to screen_background_light_temperature by default and changing it to an image from the internet when the show button is clicked. Now, I  am also creating a reset image button. So when that button is clicked, I want the imageView to be converted back to screen_background_light_temperature. How do I do that?

Below is what the XML code of the image view is used to set the background of the image view to transparent initially.

```
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
```

I just want to know how do I set this programmatically using java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Vector drawables backward compatibility solution](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution)

> The android.support.v7.appcompat package has added a number of
> features to make it easy to use vector drawables. Firstly, when you
> use android.support.v7.appcompat package with ImageView or with
> subclasses such as ImageButton and FloatingActionButton, you can use
> the new app:srcCompat attribute to reference vector drawables as well
> as any other drawable available to android:src:
>
> ```
> <ImageView
>   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>   app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
> ```
>
> To change drawables at runtime, you can use the setImageResource()
> method as before.

**Solution:** Use [setImageResource(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageResource(int)) method.

```
imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.screen_background_light_transparent);
```

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Glad that there are people who are so helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable. screen_background_light_transparent)
```